# Convergence in $D'(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Since $\chi_{R}$ denote the characteristic function of $R \subset \mathbb{R}$, that is, $\chi_{R} = 1$, if $x \in R$ and  $\chi_{R} = 0$, if $x \notin R$. I'm trying to show that for any $\phi \in D(\mathbb{R})$ and $\epsilon > 0$,

$\left\langle \frac{1}{\epsilon} \chi_{[-\frac{\epsilon}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{2}]}, \phi  \right\rangle \rightarrow \left\langle \delta_0, \phi \right\rangle$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Notion of convergence in $D'(\mathbb{R})$ (Is the vector space of all distributions).

Can someone help me to show this convergence, I need to present a work on the subject.

Comment: Write out the action on the left hand side; what is $\langle{}\epsilon^{-1}\chi_{[-\epsilon/2, \epsilon/2]}, \phi\rangle{}$ equal to, by definition? Then use the continuity of $\phi$ to say what this should be approaching as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Express $\left\langle \frac{1}{\epsilon} \chi_{[-\frac{\epsilon}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{2}]}, \phi  \right\rangle$ as an integral (with variable $x$) and do a variable change to $y = x/\epsilon.$

Comment: Or you can use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: I can't write the action on the left @Chris

Comment: Why can I do it in integral form? @md2perpe

Comment: @FCl. If $f$ is a locally integrable function then $\langle f, \varphi \rangle := \int f(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx.$

Comment: Not to dump another "best approach", but this is literally just the fundamental theorem of calculus... or the mean value theorem or anything really if you just write out the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_{\epsilon}$ denote the distribution given, for all $\phi\in\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})$, by
$$
\langle T_{\epsilon},\phi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\chi_{[-\frac{\epsilon}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{2}]}(x) \phi(x)\ dx\ .
$$
The question is about showing $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}T_{\epsilon}=\delta_0$ in the topological space $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R})$.

Just like in more elementary situations, this means showing that for all $U$ open in $\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ which contains $\delta_0$, there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all $\epsilon\in(0,\epsilon_0) $, we have $T_{\epsilon}\in U$.
This in turn means showing for every bounded set $B$ in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})$, that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}||T_{\epsilon}-\delta_0||_B = 0
$$
where $||T||_B$ denotes $\sup_{\phi\in B}|\langle T,\phi\rangle|$ for every distribution $T$.

Now
$$
\langle T_{\epsilon}-\delta_0,\phi\rangle=
\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}^{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(\phi(x)-\phi(0))\ dx
$$

$$
=\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}(\phi(\epsilon s)-\phi(0))\ ds
$$
By the mean value theorem, $|\phi(\epsilon s)-\phi(0)|\le \epsilon|s|\times \sup_{z\in\mathbb{R}}|\phi'(z)|$.

From this we immediately get
$$
||T_{\epsilon}-\delta_0||_B\le
\epsilon\times\frac{1}{2}\times\sup_{\phi\in B}\sup_{z\in\mathbb{R}}|\phi'(z)|\ .
$$
Finally, a subset $B$ in $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is bounded iff 1) there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\forall\phi\in B, {\rm supp}(\phi)\subset K$ and 2) $\forall k\ge 0, \sup_{\phi\in B}\sup_{z\in\mathbb{R}}|\phi^{(k)}(z)|$ is finite.